Slow front end in notebook whilst another is runing on a different kernel
I wish to work on a project whilst another is working in the background.
As such I utilise two different notebooks each running on a different kernel, let's call them kernel-1 and kernel-2.
However, with one notebook running on kernel-1, the front end of both notebooks, not just the one running in kernel-1, but also the one that is not running in kernel-2, becomes unusably slow and unresponsive.
This seems like I might have got a configuration option set up incorrectly or something. Is there any setting which can alleviate this problem?
Or is this really a limitation of Mathematica whereby the front end of all notebooks slows down if one of them is running a process? Even if they are using different kernels?
I am on MacOS using Mathematica version 13.3
